# Cannot share media file to PC

Tags: macos, windows, home-sharing

I want to share my media files on my Mac to my home network, however when I tried to access them from my PC I was asked for username and password. I'm sure I entered them correctly (I mean I can log out and log in my Mac no problem), but it kept saying `unknown user name or bad password`. What could possible cause the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is an excellent start but you **may** still get the same error message as Windows will often want to know the domain of the username (not "Domain" with a capital D).

When you log into a PC over the network from another PC your username will often take the form of:

```
[PCNAME]\[USERNAME]
[PASSWORD]
```

So if my pc was called stevespc with a username of steve and a password of 1234:

```
stevespc\steve
1234
```

This is so that the PC will know where to get the authentication information from. If you leave off the [PCNAME] then it will assume that it is using credentials from the computer you are logging in from and not the username and password that you want to get to (with a username/password from the target PC).

so you may have to add the computer name of the mac. If you can't recall it you can use the IP address as well. Like this:

```
192.168.0.1\steve
1234
```

It's annoying and can be confusing at first but once you learn the trick its no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be a bit confusing for people when sharing from a Mac to Windows the first time. What are you using as your username? On a Mac, you have an account name and an account ID, usually your name. For example, if the display (account) name is "John Smith", your username or account ID is probably "johnsmith". If you aren't sure what yours is, open Finder and navigate to "/Users". The folder that has a house icon is your user folder and named according to your username. This is what you will use on a Windows machine when asked for a username.

If that didn't work then you need to enable File Sharing on your Mac and specify a username and password for Windows users to use. To do this:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click "Sharing"
3. Select "File Sharing"
4. Click "Options"
5. Check the box marked "Share files and folders using SMB"
6. Check the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog next to your account name and enter your password
7. Click "OK" and "Done" and enable File Sharing

You should now be able to access your specified files from Windows